# How to concatenate strings with newline character in RPGLE?

Tags: string, rpgle

For a Rest API, I've to concatenate strings that are separated by the newline character. This string is used for HMAC calculation.

I already have tried different hex-values as separator like x'25' x'13' x'10' but nothing delivered the expected HMAC.

```
// working PHP example

//

// variables

$method = "POST";

$uri = "https://www.real.de/api/v1/units/";  

$body = "";

$timestamp = 1411055926;

$secretKey = "a7d0cb1da1ddbc86c96ee5fedd341b7d8ebfbb2f5c83cfe0909f4e57f05dd403";

// 

function signRequest($method, $uri, $body, $timestamp, $secretKey)
{

$string = implode("\n", [ $method, $uri, $body, $timestamp, ]);

return hash_hmac('sha256', $string, $secretKey);

}

// expected HMAC 

// 75312eabe66e4b9e74552a5e8959456d69cfa52a7cae9049093aede4bcdf71e7

// code RPGLE

yLf = x'25';

yString = %trim(yMethod)
+ yLf
+ %trim(yUrl)
+ yLf
+ %trim(yBody)
+ yLf
+ %trim(yTima);

// the string and the secret key then are converted to ASCII 

// the HMAC is calculated by the API 'Qc3CalculateHMAC'
```

The generated HMAC by the RPGLE doesn't match the expected HMAC. When testing with a string without newline character, everything works fine.

Comment: In EBCDIC correct value are `CR = x'0D'`  and `LF x'0A'` and you must use both CR+LF. You use `10` and `13` that are DECIMAL value, not HEX. If doesn't work try `New Line (NL) = 0x15`

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question...

Assuming you're working on an English system, EBCDIC CCSID 37, then you want to use and EBCDIC `x'0d'` for carriage return and `x'25'` for line feed.

Those values will be translated into ASCII CR `x'0d'` and LF `x'0a'` respectively.

But it seems you'll already using the right hex value.

How are you converting to ASCII?  The iconv() API is the best choice...

Assuming you're using a supported version of IBM i...you might be able to take advantage of enhancements to RPG's CCSID support to implicitly convert the EBCDIC strings...

```
dcl-s var1 char(100) ccsid(*utf8); // special value *UTF8 = CCSID 1208
dcl-s var2 char(100) ccsid(00367); // ANSI X3.4 ASCII standard; USA
dcl-s var3 char(100) ccsid(00437); // PC Data; PC Base; USA
```

Also depends on what you're using to send the HTTP request.

Comment: I'm using qdcxlate(yLen:yString:'QTCPASC') for converting from EBCDIC to ASCII. What do think is the right expression for "\n" in EBCDIC?

Comment: @hohde ..yeah that's outdated ... use iconv() instead...or the built in conversion support...

Answer (score 0):

'\n' is the "newline" character, x'15'.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found a solution in RPG yet, I'm calling the PHP script from RPG as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

agree with others, CR + LF:
(x'0D' + x'25')